# Load-time linking with C++Builder DLL in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, linker, c++builder, dynamic-linking

Is it possible to use a C++Builder DLL in a VC++ application using load-time linking?
If so, how is this done? I tried to build the VC++ application against my C++Builder .lib file, but got an error indicating that VC++ thought the .lib file was corrupt.
Is it possible to generate a VC++-friendly .lib file? Or is there an easier way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up doing it using the "Stubbing Out Functions" method described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313

Answer (score 0):

Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero IDEs include an IMPLIB.EXE command-line tool to generate a compatible import .lib file from a .dll file.  See if VC++ has a similar tool.